# IntelliJ 14 keeps switching encoding to UTF-8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8

I have a project which is encoded in ISO-8859-1 (an historic choice that I can't change).

I Set my IDE, IntelliJ 14.1.1 Ultimate, to in ISO-8859-1 everywhere : 
[My encoding setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoNtw.png)

(My code is in the folder specificaly set in ISO-8859-1)

The encoding.xml looks good:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="Encoding" defaultCharsetForPropertiesFiles="windows-1252">
    <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
    <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/mydir" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
    <file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/mydir/...ASpecificJavaFileThatIveTroubleWith.java" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
    <file url="PROJECT" charset="ISO-8859-1" />
  </component>
</project>
```

My .idea is not on commited on git because it's not the standard IDE.

But when I Work on some file, intelliJ keeps switching the encoding to UTF-8 on save. I converted the file to ISO-8859-1 several times, opened it with another editor to be sure that is no UTF-8 char remaining. But despite my efforts, after a few edits, the file is automatically switched to UTF-8.

I restart the IDE several times, no change.

Any hint?

Comment: Just curious, but does the file contain any characters that have different encodings in the two character sets? I.e. anything with ISO-8859-1 code greater than `0x7F`?

Comment: did you read their [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/)? Maybe has something to do with vcs.

Comment: (No IntelliJ at hand.) The javac compiler must be ISO-8859-1 too. Or project specific settings are overriden. For *.java I almost would port the project to UTF-8 (using native2ascii for instance).

Comment: @Jim Garrison : Yes I've some 0xE9 and 0xE0 in some comments and logs.

Comment: Assuming your project is under source control (hopefully svn or git) I would bite the bullet and do the conversion.  It won't be THAT disruptive and will be much cleaner for the future.  Be brave and rip off the band-aid in one go.

Comment: @John Smith : I read that page, but i don't have the Auto-detect checkbox

Comment: @JoopEggen, how do you set the java compiler in ISO-8859-1 ? Is it possible?

Comment: Editor and compiler should use the same encoding; it is javac -encoding "ISO-88591". Of IntelliJ I suspect it is intelligent enough not to allow distinct encodings, but look in the build menu. If it would be a **maven** build, also pom.xml and settings.xml is a concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer wasn't there, i finally had the answer of one of my friend who is an intelliJ guru and he advice me to check de .editorconfig at the project root. And he was right, charset was utf-8 and when I switched it to ISO-8859-1 he stopped converting my files to utf-8.

I guess disabling EditorConfig Plugin will works too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Settings ((Ctrl | Cmd) + Alt + S)

[image: Go to File -> Settings]

Change to ISO-8859-1
[image: Change to ISO-8859-1]

Comment: Did you check the image I post? That's exactly what I set no?

Comment: Sorry about that. What file types do you try to edit? Some file types have a default encoding associated with them.

Comment: its a .java file, with no hard encoding specified.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your advices and managed to convince my boss that we need to change the project encoding.

So I start to convert everything in UTF-8, hoping that'll do the trick.

Comment: I converted all the project using iconv and everything looks good now.